# how to allow pm2 to use all of the available system memory

Tags: node.js, memory-management, pm2

I have multiple micro-services written in Node and running on pm2. Whenever there is a high traffic on any of these micro-services, the memory doesn't exceed 800 MB even though the system has more than 10GB of memory free. Instead the system becomes slow. I have used only the below command with no additional settings to start the services.

```
pm2 start app.js --name='app_name'
```

I have gone through the docs for pm2 but it only mention about limiting the memory usage using **max-memory-restart**. Is there a way I can make sure my micro-services use all the available system memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whenever there is a high traffic on any of these micro-services, the memory doesn't exceed 800 MB even though the system has more than 10GB of memory free. Instead the system becomes slow.

You need to look at CPU metrics too, not just memory. More likely than not, those services aren't starved for memory and would begin to swap out to disk, but are just working your server's CPUs.

Profiling your services wouldn't hurt either, to find any possible bottlenecks or stalls that occur during high load.

> Is there a way I can make sure my micro-services use all the available system memory.

Yes, there is: use more memory in those services. There's no intrinsic limit unless you've configured one.

Comment: I checked the CPU and it was completely used up. Do you think it possible to handle this if i use Cluster Mode?

Comment: Cluster mode on the same underpowered machine would only hurt things. Profile your code, figure out the bottlenecks, fix them -- or get a more powerful system to run your code on.